# Unable to set UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I have a `UINavigationController` named `Tab View`, `UIViewController` named `FirstView` and another `UIViewController` named `SecondView`

`FirstView` is the RootView of the `Tab View`, I would like to change the RootView of the `Tab View` Programatically.

I tried

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(NSArray(SecondView), animated: true);
```

But it give the error:

> Cannot Invoke initializer for type 'NSArray' with an argument list of type ((SecondView).Type)

Also tried:

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(NSArray([SecondView]), animated: true);
```

This also gives the same error.

Comment: Reread the [Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) chapter to find out how to use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set actual objects as view controllers, not class references. So initialise new SecondView controller and insert in viewControllers array as first object.

Comment: this works, but it shows black screen after changing the rootView

Comment: This means view was not loaded. You should properly initialise view controller and its view.

Comment: but it is automatically initialized when the Class file is created, And i can able to see the view when i set that view as rootView in the StoryBoard Interface

Comment: Instantiate view controller from storyboard then.